# EF Core - Return mapped Many-to-Many relationship from OData using Automapper

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, odata, automapper

Info

The app type is a Hosted Blazor web-assembly. And below are the versions of the nuget packages I am using. There is an error that occurs when trying to expand a navigation property that is a many-to-many relationship. The classes are mapped to DTO classes that flattens the middle relationship class.

- .Net core Version="3.1"
- AutoMapper Version="10.0.0"
- AutoMapper.AspNetCore.OData.EFCore Version="2.0.1"
- AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping Version="4.0.1"
- AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection Version="8.0.1"
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server Version="3.2.1"
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData Version="7.5.0"

To run this repo, you will need the free version of SQL Server or better

Set the EfCoreAutomapperOdata.Server project as the startup project and navigate to the Courses page (https://localhost:5001/courses) and click on either course. This will throw the following error:

`System.InvalidOperationException: No generic method 'Include' on type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic. at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.FindMethod(Type type, String methodName, Type[] typeArgs, Expression[] args, BindingFlags flags)...`

Models

See [here - Entity Models](https://github.com/adixon501/efcore-automapper-odata/tree/master/EfCoreAutomapperOdata/Server/Data/Models) and [here - Dto Models](https://github.com/adixon501/efcore-automapper-odata/tree/master/EfCoreAutomapperOdata/Shared/Models) for class definition

Automapper Config

```cs
    public class AutomapperConfig : Profile
    {
        public AutomapperConfig()
        {
            CreateMap<Instructor, InstructorDto>();
            CreateMap<InstructorDto, Instructor>();
            
            CreateMap<Course, CourseDto>()
                .ForMember(dto => dto.Students, opt => {
                    opt.MapFrom(_ => _.Students.Select(y => y.Student));
                });
            CreateMap<CourseDto, Course>()
                .ForMember(ent => ent.Students, ex => ex
                    .MapFrom(x => x.Students.Select(y => new CourseStudent {
                        CourseId = x.Id,
                        StudentId = y.Id
                    })));
    
            CreateMap<Student, StudentDto>()
                .ForMember(dto => dto.Courses, opt => {
                    opt.MapFrom(x => x.Courses.Select(y => y.Course));
                })
                .ForMember(dto => dto.Friends, opt => {
                    opt.MapFrom(x => x.Friends.Select(y => y.Friend));
                });
            CreateMap<StudentDto, Student>()
                .ForMember(ent => ent.Courses, ex => ex
                    .MapFrom(x => x.Courses.Select(y => new CourseStudent
                    {
                        StudentId = x.Id,
                        CourseId = y.Id
                    })));
        }
    }
```

Startup

```cs
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // ------ Some code removed for brevity ------

            services.AddOData();
            services.AddAutoMapper(cfg => { cfg.AddExpressionMapping(); },typeof(AutomapperConfig));

            // ------ Some code removed for brevity ------
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            // ------ Some code removed for brevity ------

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.EnableDependencyInjection();
                endpoints.Select().Filter().OrderBy().Count().Expand().MaxTop(1000);
                endpoints.MapODataRoute("odata", "odata", GetEdmModel());
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
            });
        }

        private IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
        {
            var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            builder.EntitySet<CourseDto>("Courses");
            builder.EntitySet<InstructorDto>("Instructors");
            builder.EntitySet<StudentDto>("Students");

            return builder.GetEdmModel();
        }
    }
```

Course Controller

```cs
    public class CourseController : ODataController
    {
        protected readonly BlazorContext _context;
        protected readonly IMapper _mapper;

        public CourseController(BlazorContext context, IMapper mapper)
        {
            _context = context;
            _mapper = mapper;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ODataRoute("Courses")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get(ODataQueryOptions<CourseDto> options)
        {
            return Ok(await _context.Course.GetAsync(_mapper, options));
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [ODataRoute("Courses({id})")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Get([FromODataUri] int id, ODataQueryOptions<CourseDto> options)
        {
            return Ok((await _context.Course.GetAsync(_mapper, options)).Where(s => s.Id == id).ToList());
        }
    }
```

Sample odata api query that fails

`/odata/Courses?$expand=Students`

Repro

I have built demo Blazor WASM app for this issue to reproduce

[Repository](https://github.com/adixon501/efcore-automapper-odata)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### General Setup

To make expansions work, you need to allow for the `$expand` [query option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/concepts/queryoptions-overview#expand) to be used. Configure it explicitly like so:

```cs
private IEdmModel GetEdmModel()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    builder.EntitySet<EstimateDto>(nameof(MyContext.Estimates))
        .EntityType
        .Expand(); // <-- allow expansion

    builder.EntitySet<TypeDto>(nameof(MyContext.Types))
        .EntityType
        .Expand(); // <-- allow expansion

    builder.EntitySet<SubTypeDto>(nameof(MyContext.SubTypes));
    
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

You will also need to update your AutoMapper map, to allow the queries to be successfully mapped to a DTOs:

```cs
public class AutoMapperConfig : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperConfig()
    {
        CreateMap<Estimate, EstimateDto>()
            .ForMember(
                dto => dto.Types,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.EstimateTypes.Select(y => y.Type)));

        // The following mapping is needed for expansion to work:
        CreateMap<EstimateTypeRel, TypeDto>()
            .ForMember(
                dto => dto.SubTypes,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Type));

        CreateMap<Type, TypeDto>()
            .ForMember(
                dto => dto.SubTypes,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.SubTypes.Select(y => y.SubType)));

        CreateMap<SubTypeRel, SubTypeDto>();
    }
}
```

With that configuration being setup, there are at least two possible solutions to this issue, depending on your requirements:

#### A) Only expand `Types`

If you only want to expand `Types`, you will need to change your AutoMapper mappings by adding a `.Where(z => z != null)` clause, because as the exception tells you, `null` values are not allowed in collections, but OData includes them for the non-expanded `SubType` entities:

```cs
public class AutoMapperConfig : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperConfig()
    {
        CreateMap<Estimate, EstimateDto>()
            .ForMember(
                dto => dto.Types,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(
                    x => x.EstimateTypes.Select(y => y.Type)
                        .Where(z => z != null))); // <-- filter out null values

        CreateMap<EstimateTypeRel, TypeDto>()
            .ForMember(
                dto => dto.SubTypes,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(x => x.Type));

        CreateMap<Type, TypeDto>()
            .ForMember(
                dto => dto.SubTypes,
                opt => opt.MapFrom(
                    x => x.SubTypes.Select(y => y.SubType)
                        .Where(z => z != null))); // <-- filter out null values

        CreateMap<SubTypeRel, SubTypeDto>();
    }
}
```

Then you can use the following query:

```
https://localhost:5001/odata/Estimates(1)?$expand=Types
```

#### B) Also expand `SubTypes`

The alternative is to expand the `SubTypes` property as well, so the collection can be properly filled. To expand DTO mapped properties over multiple levels, use the `$expand` query option in your query string like so:

```
https://localhost:5001/odata/Estimates(1)?$expand=Types($expand=SubTypes)
```

Comment: The $expand OData command handles the include statements dynamically in the Automapper GetAsync extension method

Comment: I’m using Automapper expression mapping: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource).html              And I’m also using the Automapper OData nuget: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.OData

Comment: Then this needs to be investigated a bit more. However, the solution I provided does work (I am aware of the packages you are using).

Comment: Beware that there seem to exist some (unreported) bugs in the `AutoMapper.AspNetCore.OData.EFCore` package, when using many-to-many relationships, especially when multiple many-to-many relationships on different levels are being used. These will surface when [#226](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/226) or [#2028](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/2028) apply.

Comment: I also created an issue on Automapper/Automapper.Extensions.Odata

https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.OData/issues/57

Comment: I remember looking through the OData extension code back then. There where definitely issues in there and it looked like they were still actively working an basic features. So moving this issue to their repo is probably a good idea.